# How to quit tasksel instalation stalled with error "write access unavailable, cannot proceed"?

Tags: tasksel

I have a minimal Ubuntu Server 16.04 installation on an old x86_64 desktop PC. Tried installing graphic UI with `tasksel` (selected Lubuntu desktop and OpenSSH Server), but near 90% of process at `Configuring memtest86+` I got the following error:

```
EXT4-fs (sda3): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
EXT4-fs (sda1): write access unavailable, cannot proceed
```

and now `tasksel` is stalled.

The whole `sda` disk is not actually mounted, root and home directories are mounted from `sdb1` and `sdb3`. The system boots from the `sdb` disk (it's selected in BIOS). Swap uses `sdb2` partition. So I'm not sure why `sda` got involved.

How can I fix it or interrupt the process without breaking things?

Via another console I mounted `sda1` and `sda3`, but of course `tasksel` is still frozen.

Also, `tasksel` was started by root user, `ps -ef` shows it as root's process.

Comment: You need to inspect what does your `/etc/fstab`. Do a recovery-mode boot, so you must `mount -o remount, rw / `and see where is sda in fstab file.

Comment: ok, I killed `tasksel` process, ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` with `sda` partitions mounted, it seems nothing broke..

Answer (score 0):

It seems nothing bad happened from killing `tasksel` process, thus I post it as an answer.

I killed `tasksel` process and ran usual commands to clean up and fix package system:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

`dpkg --configure -a` command froze for a second and I mounted `sda` partitions. It found Fedora distribution on that disk and finished fixing packages successfully. My guess is that grub configuration needed access to the disk.